# How do you see your party members' current actions in Tyranny?

Tags: tyranny

Is it possible to view the current action of a party member during combat in Tyranny? For example if I cast a spell with one character, select a different character, and then select the first again, can I see the spell that I just queued up? If this is possible where is this displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the current action as it is highlighted in the action bar of the character.
But once the action is triggered, you can't.
You should try to chain action ( shift + clicks ) to make the action queue pop out.